# Fixed Value for same Composite Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have been trying to create a database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I am trying to have a fixed value when I am using the same composite key.

To be more clear:

```
| CrewID | Phone | Email         |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| 565    | 210   | a@hotmail.com |
| 565    | 212   | a@hotmail.com |
| 565    | 213   | a@hotmail.com |
| 935    | 641   | b@hotmail.com |
| 935    | 646   | b@hotmail.com |
```

Basically `CrewID`, `Phone` is the composite key, allowing multiple phone numbers for the same `CrewID`, but I want the email to be locked for each unique ID.

So whenever I enter new data, if the ID is the same, auto fill email with the email of the first entry with that specific ID.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. What have you tried? Any research? Perhaps a `trigger` to validate the data on both `insert` and `update`? Do you have a question or are you just seeking authorization? What does "first entry" mean since there is no order to rows in a table?

Comment: "but I want the email to be locked for each unique ID" which unique ID? Crew? Phone? Both? This is actually a bad database design, if you are trying to prevent multiple different email addresses, you should be storing them in a different table (Crew?) rather than building a mechanism to try and keep them the same.

Comment: @DaleK The focus of the database is not on the mails. To be frank this whole idea is kinda optional and I just want to implement it to make data entry easier in the end. But to answer your question as best as i can. I want the same email for the same CrewID, exactly as shown in the table above. So as HABO mentioned, I might try to make a trigger which automatically fills the email collumn if it detects that the crewID has not changed. I am not sure if that can even work though. If nothing works, I will end up splitting the tables as you said.

Comment: Seems like you need 3 tables. A `Crew` table, a `Phone` table and a "junction" table for the many to many join between 2 prior tables. Then your `Email` column goes in the table that it actually related to and it has a `UNIQUE INDEX`/`CONSTRAINT` on it.

Comment: One should always design a database correctly regardless of how optional a feature is today, because otherwise you introduce technical debt for tomorrow. If you still wish to do it as you say, you should autofill it in your client interface, and disable editing on any further records added to the same CrewID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it rather quickly. My initial thought was to keep it simple and split the phone and crew tables, but I wanted to try something more advanced. It was not necessary in the end.

I just put `PhoneNum` (PK), `Description`, `CrewID` (FK) on a new table, and kept the `Crew` table simple with just `CrewID` (PK) and `Email`. Now, for each unique `CrewID` I have a single email, while the `Phone` table allows me to store multiple phone numbers.

Comment: You've learnt a lesson in database normalization: using more tables and relationships, and doing things properly, means you don't need to tie yourself in knots for the coding